# bootstrap-gallery, activating plugin on gallery container

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to use [bootstrap-gallery](https://github.com/iekadou/bootstrap-gallery) in my rails 4 app.

I've followed the simple instructions outside of not understanding what is meant by:

```
3.  activate the plugin on the gallery container

$('.gallery').bootstrapGallery();
```

I have attempted to add this to the top of my view with:

```
<script>
$('.gallery').bootstrapGallery();
</script>
```

But the JS doesn't appear to execute when I click on an image (I'm just taken to the image URL), and I get the following errors in the JS console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMarker' of undefined
```

Pointers on where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT:** this is what I have in my view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap-gallery" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-gallery" %>

<div class="gallery row">
  <% @post.assets.each do |asset| %>
     <a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4" href=<%= asset.asset.url(:medium) %>>
       <img src=<%= asset.asset.url(:medium) %> alt="">
     </a>
  <% end %>
</div>

<script>
var ready;
ready = function() {
  $('.gallery').bootstrapGallery();
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
</script>
```

Still running into the same issue with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.gallery').bootstrapGallery({});
```

for some reason, the script is expecting options to be passed to it; if you don't need to change anything, you can set the options empty.